# Compare ObjectIDs for greater/smaller in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am aware you can query MongoDB for an object ID using the `$gt` and `$lt` operators. However, I would like to know how to compare two object IDs in this way but in plain JavaScript — not through a query.

I'm aware the `ObjectID` object has an `equals` method, but obviously that isn't what I need to test for greater/smaller than. I couldn't convert them to a timestamp and do the comparison that way because of the structure of ObjectIDs (with the incrementing counter at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `ObjectID` objects to strings so that you can compare them:

```
if (oid1.toString() > oid2.toString()) { ... }
```

Or let JavaScript do the string conversions for you and just compare them directly:

```
if (oid1 > oid2) { ... }
```

Comment: Is this all there is to it?

Comment: Can `ObjectId`s be compared to `Date`s and vice versa?